# Update personal token for github

Tags: git, github

My personal access token has expired for GitHub, I really can't work figure out how to update the personal access token on the command line.

```
git push
Password for 'https://PERSONAL_ACCESS_TIME@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepor.git/'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am very confused

Comment: Did you read the instructions at https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token ? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have read the github docs, the URL contains the old token and I can't figure out how to update it

Comment: So you question is about finding where the token is _saved_, not _regenerating_ it?

Comment: @GemmaMorriss Related: [Need help walking through the process of pushing code from a codebase in VSCode onto Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587196/15032688)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not save the token in the URL.  That's insecure, because anybody who can read the configuration file can see your credentials.  The [Git FAQ explains how to set up and use a credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials).

To remove the token from your URL, do this:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myuser/myrepor.git
```

Then, after setting up your credential helper, when you push, Git will prompt you for your credentials.  Enter your username when prompted, and provide the token when prompted for the password.

Answer (score 4):

You can use github command line to make a new login with new/regenerated token

1. Install github CLI:

   `brew install gh`
2. Login to gh:

   `gh auth login`
3. Follow the steps and paste your token when needed
   [steps for this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPypW.jpg)