# Need help walking through the process of pushing code from a codebase in VSCode onto Github

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a few projects that I have already started working on. I wanted to track all changes I was making, so I decided to initialize a repository and push all the changes onto Github.

I followed these steps:

1. git remote add origin git@github.com:Anirudh-RK/Audiophile-App.git
2. git branch -M main (or master)
3. git push -u origin main

At the last step, I enter my credentials, and paste the auth token given by github. It throws all sorts of different errors however, such as only read access is allowed, write permission is denied, etc. What do I do here? I get repeatedly stuck at this step.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: it may be good to show the specific error(s) you're getting

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "auth token" or "credentials"; you are using SSH in your remote URL. Did you make an SSH key at GitHub?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the `gh` command line tool to manage authorization makes their job easier. After using the `gh` command as below, all the guidance you need can be done step-by-step from the command line. The `gh` command line tool can be used to create repositories that are not available on GitHub. It is necessary to use the `gh repo create` command once to create the repository as shown below. Then using the `git push` command will work if there is only one branch; additionally, if multiple branches are created on the remote repository, it is necessary to select the targeted branch.

```sh
# start version control in repository
git init -b main

# select tracked files and commit
git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"

# To push the repository to GitHub
gh repo create
```

Follow [this link](https://cli.github.com/) to use the `gh` command line tool on Windows OS.

---

###### References

- [Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @AnirudhRK It's possible to have authorization issues when not using the `gh` command line tool; Trying to do the authorization manually is a waste of time in most cases.